# How to connect MongoDB server via SSH Tunnel with NodeJS Cluster (multiple worker)

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, ssh-tunnel

I am implementing `cluster` in my NodeJS so maximize the performance.

The problem comes when I connect to MongoDB via SSH, the first connection by `worker` to MongoDB server via SSH is success but when the the rest of `worker` trying to connect to MongoDB will encounter error `{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}` where i believe the port is in use and it suppose to be connected once only.

Below is my code:

`server.js`

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const mongodb = require("./server/services/mongodb")
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const https = require('https').createServer(serverOptions, app)
const http = require('http').createServer(app);


if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        let worker = cluster.fork();
    }

} else {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`)
    // Workers can share any TCP connection
    // In this case it is an HTTP server
    //------------Turn on Web Server

    https.listen(webserverConfig.port, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:' + webserverConfig.port);
    })

    http.listen(80, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:80');
    });
}
```

`mongodb.js`

```
const tunnel = require("tunnel-ssh")
const mongo = require("mongodb")
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;

var config = require("../config/config.js")
var dbConfig = new config.db(config.env)
var url = "mongodb://" + dbConfig.username + dbConfig.password + "localhost:27017/" + dbConfig.name;

var DB



var dbServer = tunnel(sshConfig, function (error, tnl) {
  if (error) {
    return console.log({ desc: 'configuration error on SSH connection :', error });
  }
  console.log("using SSH now")
  connect()
});
// Use a listener to handle errors outside the callback
dbServer.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log({ desc: 'Something bad happened on SSH connection :', err });
});


function connect() {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    };
    db.on("close", () => {
      console.log("Mongodb connection closed")
      connect()
    })

    DB = db.db(config.name)
    console.log("MongoDB Succesfully connected to", dbConfig.name);
  });
}
```

`Console Error`

```
MongoDB Succesfully connected to _____
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}
{"desc":"Something bad happened on SSH connection :","err":{"errno":"EADDRINUSE","code":"EADDRINUSE","syscall":"bind","address":"127.0.0.1","port":27017}}

//(Appear 8 times due to 8 cores)
```

It working fine without cluster, please advise and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `imports` need to put inside the `else` block of `cluster.master`, then it will work.

`server.js`

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        let worker = cluster.fork();
    }

} else {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`)
    // Workers can share any TCP connection
    // In this case it is an HTTP server
    const cluster = require('cluster');
    const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    const mongodb = require("./server/services/mongodb")
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express()
    const https = require('https').createServer(serverOptions, app)
    const http = require('http').createServer(app);
    //------------Turn on Web Server

    https.listen(webserverConfig.port, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:' + webserverConfig.port);
    })

    http.listen(80, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:80');
    });
}
```